# Best mode for a router

Tags: iphone, ipad, router, 802.1x

I have this wireless router I use to connect my iPhone and iPad. This router has 4 settings:

- 802.11b/n Mixed
- just 802.11g
- 802.11b/g/n
- 802.11g/n

Which one should I choose to have maximum speed on my iDevices?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with:

- 802.11g/n

That setting covers the first generation iPad through to the latest iPad that got announced yesterday as well as the first generation iPhone through to the latest iPhone 4S. Your devices should pick the faster protocol ([N](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009)) if they support it. If not, they'll use the slower protocol ([G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11g-2003)).

But between G and N you've got just about all modern wireless devices covered so your network should be friendly to everything WiFi you bring in to it.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much any new iOS based device, including the Apple TV etc, will happily use Wireless "n" (150Mb or even 300Mb).

Practically nothing that you own will still use "b" (11Mb) - the only devices I have are Nintendo DS, and an ancient Palm organiser.

Almost everything else you might have that isn't particular new, or isn't Apple kit, will support "g" (54mb) - Playstations, older windows laptops, non apple phones/tablets, portable gaming systems like the PSP etc etc.

So, for preference I would have G/N.  If you have a kid with a DS, consider B/G/N.  Bear in mind that Nintendo DS cannot accept WPA authentication, and do WEP as a maximum, and thus if you want to use them, you run the risk of reducing the security on all the other devices.